# Starting my own application at the startup

Tags: filesystems, kernel, busybox, petalinux

I am working on zc702 board having ARM Cortex A 9 processor. I have a binary that I got after cross-compilation for ARM (LED blinking). Now I want that this file should execute as soon as the the kernel (petalinux) boots. 
I am having initramfs as my root file system.
How do I proceed to do it? What files I have to modify?

Please note that this is a volatile system, so I cannot make required changes in a running system. I have to instead put my binary in some folder in file system (rootfs.cpio). But where ?

Comment: I added the "busybox" tag here as I believe that is what petalinux uses and it manages init services, which is what you want to use for this.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' Thansk for adding the tag.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Petalinux uses /etc/rcS.d for its init scripts, the following is a step by step that should allow you to resolve this issue:
http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/55998.htm

Please let us know if you have any further issues.